# "People" or "peoples" when referring to an indigenous population?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

Let's say we are talking about the indigenous pukapuka who live in Pluto.

What is correct: "the pukapuka people" or "the pukapuka peoples"?

I've read somewhere the usage of "peoples" in this context, and it has surprised me.

Comment: _The native peoples of Canada._

Comment: Churchill's _[History of the English-Speaking Peoples](http://www.amazon.com/Churchills-History-English-Speaking-Peoples/dp/1566198135)_.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

"Peoples" means a group of populations. So for example "the native American peoples" means the tribes that were living in America before Columbus. "the pukapuka peoples" would mean "the group of tribes/groups collectively known as pukapuka", whereas "the pukapuka people" would mean "the group of people known as (the) pukapuka (tribe/group/etc.)"

Comment: Right. `Person` = an individual human being. `People`= a group of `person`s. `Peoples`= a group of such groups.

Comment: @T.E.D.: To me, this comment is the real answer. It's short and it's clear. *Every*, and I mean **EVERY** other answer on this entire site, among all the duplicate questions, either don't give any explanation at all to justify the existence of *peoples* as a correct term, or they contain ambiguity that dilutes the message. (This very answer says both "pukapuka peoples" and "pukapuka people" are correct. And I get it. But to someone who is having trouble grasping the distinction to begin with, that doesn't help.)

Answer (score -4):

"People: Persons composing community, tribe, race, or nation."

*OED*