# Which is correct: "this people" or "these people"? 

Tags: grammatical-number

**This** people or **these** people?

Different sources suggest different ways. What's the right way and why?

Comment: Related: [Person, Persons, People, Peoples](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2677/).

Comment: I saw this question, and it's not really what  I was looking for. thx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I too have seen some conflicting articles on this.  In general, I use it as follows:

If I'm using `people` as the plural of person, then I treat it as plural.

> These people are going to be the death of me.

If `people` is referring to a community, cultural group, etc. then I treat it as singular.

> This indigenous people was subjugated by invaders from afar.

I'll also note that used in this last sense, `peoples` (meaning multiple cultural groups, or what have yoU) is also valid and would then be plural.

> These indigenous peoples were all prospering at the turn of the century.

Comment: This was sort of my approach. Thx

Comment: This is exactly correct. People is unfortunately a confusing noun, it that it acts as singular form for the original meaning, but also the plural form of 'person' in Modern English.

Comment: I actually prefer to always treat "people" as plural, correctness be damned, because it will always sound OK that way - it just might not *mean* exactly the same thing.