# Correct usage of "persons" (vs. "people")

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I had a little fight about *persons* vs. *people*.

Could you advise if both of the following are correct, if possible with reference to a dictionary?

> 1. A table for two people please.
> 2. A table for two persons please.

Besides that, how would you ask for a table in a restaurant?

I read http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/persons and [Person, Persons, People, Peoples](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/person-persons-people-peoples), but they didn't really solve the question if both are correct.

I also found the last paragraph of http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/person, which suggests that (1) is "more correct", but doesn't say (2) is wrong.

Comment: You would say *A table for two, please*.

Comment: Were you hurt? :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Generally, *persons* is a decent substitute for *individuals*, and appears more in legal contexts that demand precision.

*People* is the ordinary plural of *person*.

Asking for *a table for two* or *a table for two people* is better than asking for *a table for two persons*.

Comment: I'm curious how they came to use "persons" instead of "people" legal contexts...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner It's a good question. Two things that come to mind are 1) the phrase "in person" (sometimes you're legally required to do things in person) and 2) the fact that it accords with the French plural (legalese loves itself some French and Latin).

Comment: Or perhaps a more practical reason would be that it makes form-writing easier. Saying "Person(s) affected..." is pretty convenient.

Comment: Would you say that "A table for two persons please." is wrong or that it is correct but unusal English?

Comment: It is *grammatically* correct. It is also nonstandard. Everyone will understand you, but most people will assume it was a mistake.

Comment: In the cause of explanation, I do not know why you did not actually shed a brief light at least about the "persons" of the first, second and third person. Doesn't this persons have a meaning as persons too?

Comment: @MrBrownHameed because the question never asked for that. In fact it provided a very particular context.

Comment: What kind of answer is that? Saying that we should ask for _"a table for two"_ is just ignoring the question.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner At law, people is a set of humans, but a person is a legal status – so "persons" is a set of individuals who all have the legal status of being a person. Hence a set of corporations may be referred to as persons, but not as people.

Answer (score 18):

The *NOAD* on my Mac Mini had the following notes about using *persons* instead of *people*.

> The words *people* and *persons* can both be used as the plural of *person*, but they are not used in exactly the same way. *People* is by far the more common of the two words and is used in most ordinary contexts: "a group of people"; "there were only about ten people"; "several thousand people have been rehoused". *Persons*, on the other hand, tends now to be restricted to official or formal contexts, as in "this vehicle is authorized to carry twenty persons"; "no persons admitted without a pass." In some contexts, *persons*, by pointing to the individual, may sound less friendly than *people*: "The number should not be disclosed to any unauthorized persons."

Similar notes can be found on [*Lexico*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/person) (a collaboration with *Oxford Dictionary* hosted by Dictionary.com).

Answer (score 16):

The normal plural of *person* is *people*, unless you're a bureaucrat.

Comment: Or you're discussing grammar: *first person*, *second person* and *third person* can (I guess) be called "three persons", but not "three people". :-)

Comment: I agree. Good point.

Comment: I also faced similar dilemma when developing a software application. I have a list of registered people/persons whose status will be monitored monthly. Somehow it seemed awkward to call the list "Monitored people" because in this context we have specific persons - the ones registered in the database and not some abstract group of unknown people. But I'm still not 100% sure about "Monitored persons" either. Or maybe even "Monitored personas"? :D

Comment: A plural by suppletion.

Answer (score 9):

According to [this online article from DailyWritingTips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/people-versus-persons/), the words *person* and *people* are derived from different latin origins: *persona* and *populum*, respectively.

The article goes on to suggest that both *person* and *people* can be used in their own natural plural forms; *persons* and *peoples*, but modern daily use favours the following combination:

> Singular: Person
>
> Plural: People

The entry also backs up @onomatomaniak 's assertion that *persons* is used more for legal text, but doesn't indicate that *persons* is any more precise than *people*.  The article doesn't reference any sources itself.