# What's the correct plural of person?

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Person, Persons, People, Peoples](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/person-persons-people-peoples)
>   [Correct usage of “persons” (vs. “people”)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46294/correct-usage-of-persons-vs-people)

What's the correct plural of *person*?  *Persons* or *people*?

Comment: Yes. But the second is the normal choice.

Comment: Here is a good explanation of when *persons* is the more usual choice: ( http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/people.htm )

Comment: A technicality: 'people' is a plural of 'person' only by the fiddle of _suppletion_ (a fudge to fill an observed gap).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are correct and both are required in English language, you just have to know how to use them.

*People* denotes a group, an unspecified number of people, for example:

> The people in the area have been warned about the possible risks.

*Persons* refers to persons individually and denotes an exact number which can be, or should be able to, expressed in numbers, for example:

> Which persons are responsible for this fire?

Remember that *persons* is usually used in law and legal documents, like:

> Lessor shall not be responsible for damage to Lessee’s vehicle, whether or not such damage is caused by other vehicles or persons in the parking lot and surrounding area.
>
> Only such persons who are nominated in accordance with the procedures set forth in this section ...

Comment: The reason for the legal usage is that 'persons' may include companies and the like (*legal persons*), while 'people' probably means living and breathing.

Answer (score 7):

Both are correct, and *people* has overtaken *persons* for general situations.

Most often in causal conversation, you will hear *people* used.  *Persons* is used in more formal constructs.

[image]