# Is "to one of the most genuine people I know" correct?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I am confused if I should use *persons* or *people*. *Persons* sounds weird to me.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/46294/16833 – http://english.stackexchange.com/q/62084/16833 – http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2677/16833

Answer (score 0):

People is the plural of person.Persons mostly used in law.Please see:

www.dailywritingtips.com/people-vs-persons

www.worldwidewords.org/articles/people

www.grammarist.com/usage/

Beside people is more warm than persons, so to speak.