# Is the word ''persons'' correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

I've always thought plural form of the word person as people, but in many places I've seen it as 'peoples'.
There was a sign saying
''the room takes 85 peoples max''
Is ''peoples'' also correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "persons" is correct, a more formal version of "people". However, "peoples" is awkwardly used in the example you provided; usually it's used in the context of different ethnic groups or indegenuous groups of a nation, e.g. the peoples of Siberia. The sign should have used "persons" or "people" instead.

Comment: Are you asking about "persons" (in the title) or "peoples" (in the body of your question)? Both exist, but they are different words.

Comment: There are many questions about this topic; hopefully they will help clear up your confusion. Here is one of them: [Correct usage of “persons” (vs. “people”)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46294/correct-usage-of-persons-vs-people); other linked questions can be accessed from the sidebar to the right of it.

Comment: "Awkwardly used" (as @Bobby''V0ight''Peru-------- said) is, in my opinion, an understatement. "The room takes 85 peoples max" is simply wrong, unless the room is limited to 85 ethnic groups.

Answer (score 1):

**persons**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/person?q=persons)

> "Usage:
>
> The words people and persons can both be used as the plural of person, but they are not used in exactly the same way. People is by far the more common of the two words and is used in most ordinary contexts: a group of people; there were only about ten people; several thousand people have been rehoused. Persons, on the other hand, tends now to be restricted to official or formal contexts, as in this vehicle is authorized to carry twenty persons; no persons admitted without a pass. In some contexts, persons, by pointing to the individual, may sound less friendly than people: the number should not be disclosed to any unauthorized persons."

**peoples**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/people)

> 2 (plural peoples) [TREATED AS SINGULAR OR PLURAL] The men, women, and children of a particular nation, community, or ethnic group:
>
> *the native peoples of Canada*