# does the word PERSONS exist? Should I only use it for singular? PERSON

Tags: word-usage

I need to know the correct use of this word, I am quiet confused about the plural form and singular form due to some people use it as plural persons and I was taught that the plural is people1

Comment: Have you never encountered the legal usage *...by a person or **persons** unknown?* This is a dup of [Person, Persons, People, Peoples](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/person-persons-people-peoples), but I've run out of closevotes today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grammarist explains the origin and usage of the two terms:

[People vs persons](http://grammarist.com/usage/people-persons/):

> - In modern English, people is the de facto plural of person. People and person have separate Latin origins, and they came to English at different times by different paths, but there are examples of people used as a plural of person from as early as the 14th century. Persons was the original plural, and it is possible to find examples of its use in all types of writing up to the present, but it prevails only in a few contexts, most notably law and law enforcement, and in a few common phrases (e.g., persons of interest, displaced persons, missing persons). Elsewhere, it usually gives way to people.
> - There is an old usage prescription holding that people applies to uncountable groups of individuals (e.g., Times Square was packed with people) while persons applies to groups that are easily counted (e.g., there were four persons on the balcony). But there is no good reason for this distinction, and in any case it is not consistently borne out in real-world usage.

Examples:

> - *In some of the houses there are just a few blankets, and it is not uncommon for four people to share one. [New York Times]*
> - *Between 1980 and 2002, 16,556 refugees and displaced persons were resettled in New Zealand under the Refugee Quota Programme. [New Zealand Herald]*
> - *Hundreds of people are reported to have been killed since government troops began pounding known strongholds of opposition groups. [BBC News]*
> - *He also talks of Susan’s missing persons case and facing ridicule from many members of the media and public. [Chicago Tribune]*
> - *An outbreak of salmonella which struck 68 people across the U.S. originated at Taco Bell, it has emerged. [Daily Mail]*

- See also this extract from Word Wide Words:  [People vs Persons](http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/people.htm):

Answer (score 0):

"Persons" and "people" are both accepted forms of the plural of "person". Generally, "persons" is used when the intended meaning is "multiple individuals", while "people" generally means a large group of individuals.

Even so, you rarely here the word "persons" used in everyday speech. Use "people" for the plural if there is no specific reason you need to be using "persons".