# Does the word "peoples" exist, and if so, when do you use it?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“People” or “peoples” when referring to an indigenous population?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2444/people-or-peoples-when-referring-to-an-indigenous-population)
>   [Person, Persons, People, Peoples](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/person-persons-people-peoples)

I've seen someone using the word "peoples" today, with a vehement claim that it "is NOT grammatically incorrect". I searched on the net, but I got links (such as [this](http://www.englishforums.com/English/IsItCorrectToSayPeoples/pdgvk/post.htm)) which suggests it is correct. Either way, is there a reference which could settle this issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Person, Persons, People, Peoples](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2677/10041)

Comment: [answered already here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2444/people-or-peoples-when-referring-to-an-indigenous-population)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an entry from OALD online:

**3 [countable] all the persons who live in a particular place or belong to a particular country, race, etc**

*the French people*

*the native peoples of Siberia*

So, when used in this sense, the word "people" has a plural form and it is grammatically correct.