# Countable vs. Uncountable Nouns

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

What is correct: "too much people" or "too many people"?

Comment: I think this question has been dealt with on these pages already. See previous posts.

Comment: See e.g. *[Person, Persons, People, Peoples](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2677)* and *[Correct usage of “persons” (vs. “people”)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46294)*, plus *[“People” or “peoples”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2444)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People is countable noun, despite the fact that it doesn't have ending.
So the right form is 
*too many people*.

If you want to count people, use *person*, the singular form of *people*: *one person*, *two persons*, etc.

Comment: but how can i count people? 1 people, 2 peoples, ... n peoples?

Comment: @Dantes Edited. And please include your comment in question then.

Comment: I see this as 2 different nouns. (1) people, (2) person. For latter noun it is clear that it is a countable noun. For the first one I can't determine that. Can you please clarify? Thanks

Comment: @Dantes People is the plural of person.

Comment: Of course. However, as you wrote, we count persons like this: 1 person, 2 persons, ... , n persons. I see "people" as a completely different noun (is "collective noun" the correct term?)

Comment: @Dantes It is a bit complex (and I seem to have answered your question). Further reading: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/is-people-a-countable-or-a-non-countable-noun.