# People's belongings or peoples' belongings?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

> I refuse to look after other people's belongings.
>
> I refuse to look after other peoples' belongings.

Which is correct?

We're talking about the belongings that potentially belong individually to every other person.

Not a dupe of 'people' vs 'peoples' as this is talking about the possessive of 'peoples'.

Comment: I would lean to the first, as people in itself is a collective term, therefore it need not be pluralised. Therefore the belongings of anyone else would be "other people's" belonging. However I cannot back this claim up, I would be intrigues to see other responses

Comment: possible duplicate of ["People" or "peoples" when referring to an indigenous population?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2444/people-or-peoples-when-referring-to-an-indigenous-population)

Comment: ... and once the people / peoples issue is settled, the remaining point about correct apostrophisation is genref.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*People* as a plural of *person* is a mass noun, and we don;t use a plural -s. So when forming a possessive, we only add the *'s*:

> I refuse to look after other people's belongings.

However, *people* can also be countable, when we refer to a(n ethic) group of persons: the Belgian people, the British people. Although a bit contrived, you *could* be referring to belongings that are the property of such groups.

For example:

> The artwork from the Acropolis belong to the Greek people. Some of them are now in the British museum, but I don't see why they should look after other peoples' belongings.